# Applying a user defined R codes to a data set

Tags: r

I have R codes that I would like to apply to a data file. Please see the codes below:

```
library(plyr);
library(dplyr);


ability<- function(mdl, u, b, a, c){

  J<- length(b)

  if(mdl == 1 | mdl==2 | missing(c)) {

    c<- rep(0,J)

  }
  if (mdl == 1 | missing(a)) { a<- rep(1,J)}

  x<- sum(u)

  if (x == 0) {

    th<- -log(2*J)

  }

  if(x == J){

    th<- log(2*J)

  }

  if (x == 0 | x == J) {

    sumdem<- 0.0

    for ( j in 1:J) {

      pstar<- 1/(1 + exp(-a[j] * (th - b[j])))

      phat<- c[j] + (1.0 - c[j])* pstar

      sumdem<- sumdem - a[j]**2 * phat * (1.0 - phat) * (pstar / phat)**2


    }

    se <- 1/ sqrt(-sumdem)

  }

  if (x != 0 & x != J){

    th<- log(x /(J-x))

    S<- 10;
    ccrit <- 0.001

    for ( s in 1:S) {

      sumnum <- 0.0
      sumdem <- 0.0

      for(j in 1:J){

        pstar<- 1/(1 + exp(-a[j] * (th - b[j])))

        phat<- c[j] + (1.0 - c[j])* pstar

        sumnum<- sumnum + a[j] * (u[j] - phat) *
          (pstar / phat)

        sumdem <- sumdem - a[j]**2 * phat * (1.0 - phat) *
          (pstar / phat)**2

      }

      delta<- sumnum / sumdem

      th<- th - delta

      if(abs(delta) < ccrit | s == S) {

        se<- 1/sqrt(-sumdem)

        break;

      }

    }

  }

  cat(paste("th=", th, "\n")); flush.console();

  cat(paste("se=", se, "\n")); flush.console();

  thse<- c(th, se);

  return(thse);

} 



u<-read.csv("C:\\PA\\Keystone\\Spring 018\\data\\out_sp16_ALGEBRA1.csv",header=TRUE,as.is=T);

b<- c(-0.5255,0.0645,-0.0685,0.4132,0.5103,0.6826,-0.524,-0.2108,-0.3115,0.583,-0.6093,1.1567,0.6096,-0.2789,0.1151,1.2127,-0.085,-0.2494,-0.2724,0.0433,-0.4693,0.1692,0.15,0.3255,0.6008,0.3654,-1.239,-0.7911,0.2886,0.2324,0.1885,0.6671,-0.1561,0.4412,1.4597,0.0981,0.2668,1.9483,2.0044,1.403,2.1106,1.0472); 

a<- rep(1,length(b));

u<-u[,-c(1)]

u<-as.matrix(u)

apply()
```

The argument u is a data set that I converted to matrix and would like to apply the codes to all row of the matrix. a is a vector and b is a vector. I thought about using apply() but not giving me what I want.

Thanks for your time and input.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Specifically (1) what is your function trying to do? - does the function work / have you tested it?  (2) what is the desired input to the function? 

On another note, you will have much better performance if you remove your `for` loops.  R has a lot of vectorized functions - which basically means that the for loops are implemented in a compiled language.  This is much faster and prettier than doing for loops in R.

Comment: The codes are designed to estimate students'ability using rasch model and the function has arguments mdl, u, b, a, and c. u is the student' responses to items, b is items difficulties and c is guessing parameter. When u is vector of responses by one student, the codes work. Now I want u to be the items reponses by many students.That's why I have u as a matrix which is the responses to the set of items by many students.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that each row of the u represents different students and each column represents different items so using matrix indices may help(i.e sum(u[1,]) will compute sum for overall performance or all items combined for 1st student. also I did not get what you are asking specifically in order to guide what you should do.

Comment: Thank Zakarie for your inputs. I am trying to call the function ability() using a, b, and u a and b are vectors a<-c(1.0, 1.2,0.8); b<-c(-1.0, 0.0, 1.0) and I want u to be able to supply different values of u to the function so that the function can read them once. u<-c(1,0, 0); u<-c(0,0,0)